# Laguerre function in python

Tags: python, pine-script

Tried to reproduce the following function I found in [pine script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/ngr0qRmw-CM-Laguerre-PPO-PercentileRank-Mkt-Tops-Bottoms/) on TrandingView:

```
Short = 0.1
Long = 0.3
//Laguerre PPO Code from TheLark
lag(g, p) =>
    L0 = (1 - g)*p+g*nz(L0[1])
    L1 = -g*L0+nz(L0[1])+g*nz(L1[1])
    L2 = -g*L1+nz(L1[1])+g*nz(L2[1])
    L3 = -g*L2+nz(L2[1])+g*nz(L3[1])
    f = (L0 + 2*L1 + 2*L2 + L3)/6
    f
lmas = lag(Short, hl2)
lmal = lag(Long, hl2)
//PPO Plot
ppoT = (lmas-lmal)/lmal*100
```

I fight with my lack of expertise, but I keep trying and this is a community that has been helping me a lot and I do appreciate that. I am hoping I can get this additional help here. In python I tried this:

```
Short = 0.1
Long = 0.3
def lagfunction (g,p : DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
   L0 = DataFrame([])
   L1 = DataFrame([])
   L2 = DataFrame([])
   L3 = DataFrame([])

   L0 = (1 - g)*p+g*L0.shift(1).fillna(0)
   L1 = -g*L0+L0.shift(1).fillna(0)+g*L1.shift(1).fillna(0)
   L2 = -g*L1+L1.shift(1).fillna(0)+g*L2.shift(1).fillna(0)
   L3 = -g*L2+L2.shift(1).fillna(0)+g*L3.shift(1).fillna(0)
   f = (L0 + 2*L1 + 2*L2 + L3)/6 

   return f

dataframe['hl2'] = (dataframe['high'] + dataframe['low'])/2
dataframe['lmas'] = lagfunction(Short,dataframe['hl2'])
dataframe['lmal'] = lagfunction(Long,dataframe['hl2'])
dataframe['ppoT'] = (dataframe['lmas'] - dataframe['lmal'])/dataframe['lmal']*100
```

And I get the error below. Any suggestion on how I can do this conversion without issues?

```
...
KeyError: 'lmas'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    dataframe['ppoT'] = (dataframe['lmas'] - dataframe['lmal'])/dataframe['lmal']*100
...
KeyError: 'lmas'
```

Answer (score 1):

After seeing some function examples I came up with a solution that is doing the same as the Tradingview indicator. I will leave it herein case anyone is interested in the future:

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

def laguerre(g = None, p = None):
            m = p.size
            L0 = Series(0, index = p.index)
            L1 = Series(0, index = p.index)
            L2 = Series(0, index = p.index)
            L3 = Series(0, index = p.index)
            f = Series(0, index = p.index)
    
            for i in range(1,m):
                p_L0 = L0.iloc[i - 1]
                p_L1 = L1.iloc[i - 1]
                p_L2 = L2.iloc[i - 1]
                p_L3 = L3.iloc[i - 1]
        
                L0.iloc[i] = (1-g)*p[i]+g*p_L0
                L1.iloc[i] = -g*L0[i]+p_L0+g*p_L1
                L2.iloc[i] = -g*L1.iloc[i]+p_L1+g*p_L2
                L3.iloc[i] = -g*L2.iloc[i]+p_L2+g*p_L3
    
            f = (L0 + 2*L1 + 2*L2 + L3)/6
    
            return f

dataframe['lmas'] = laguerre(Short,dataframe['hl2'])
dataframe['lmal'] = laguerre(Long,dataframe['hl2'])
```